# is there any way to edit files in minIO directly?

Tags: java, api, plugins, minio

is there any way that allow user to edit files and save them in minIO directly without going through backend program?like api or plugins

so im working on an online editing function, which u can edit ur files online on browsers, and save it after u done editing.

now our solution is: get the files from minIO, parse and deliver it to the front end, u edit it, and save the edited file to minIO through backend java program

but considering the file might be big, data parsing and transferring might be pretty slow, besides even if u just change a word, we need to save the whole file again

since i cannot find such method in sdk, i wonder if theres a 3rd party lib or plugin that allows me to edit files and save them directly in minIO without coding like
getObject(...) -> parseFile(...) -> return it to front -> get edited file from front ->  putObject(...)
in my backend program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer from somewhere else
s3 api does not allow partial mutations of objects,so theres no way